# Use the same button to trigger three events in a loop

Tags: events, buttonclick

There is one button.

The javascript program contains 3 sections.

```
//section 1

var x = 3;

console.log("x = " + x);


//section 2

x += 7;

console.log("x = " + x);


//section 3:

x += 6;

console.log("x = " + x);
```

The effect I want to achieve is:

1. I'm clicking the button - only section 1 is being executed
2. I'm clicking the button again - execution of section 2 only
3. I'm clicking the button again - execution of section 3 only
4. I'm clicking the button once more - execution of section 1 only
5. I'm clicking the button again - execution of section 2 only

and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop is not necessary, this can be done with the same event handler for the button.

As a side note, if you are looking for a way to debug step by step, that can be done using the 'Debug or Debugger' tab of the brwoser afte right click -> inspect. You can set breakpoints and run the script step by step.

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var theButton = document.getElementById("theButton");
var section = 0;

var x;
theButton.onclick = function(){
    section++;
    var temporaryResult = "Nothing";
    if(section == 4){
        section = 1;
    }
    if(section == 1){
        //Do the math
        x = 0;
        // Set the result to show
        temporaryResult = x;
    }
    if(section == 2){
        //Do the math
        x += 10;
        // Set the result to show
        temporaryResult = x;
    }
    if(section == 3){
        x -= 25;
        temporaryResult = x;
    }
    output.innerHTML = temporaryResult;
    //For console log:
    console.log(temporaryResult);
}
```

```html
<div id="output">Results here</div>
<button id="theButton">Next</Button>
```